# Formatted scientific names from R to LaTeX (using Sweave or knitr)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, taxonomy, sweave

I am implementing a function `print_name` in the package [taxlist](https://github.com/kamapu/taxlist).
For example, I can format a name for markdown:

```
library(taxlist)
data(Easplist)
print_name(Easplist, 206, style="markdown")
```

The output in the console is then:

```
[1] "*Cyperus papyrus* L."
```

I can use this command for example to mention a species in the content of a markdown document by `` `r I(print_name(Easplist, 206, style="markdown"))` ``, where the scientific name appears as italics and the author name does not.

I would like to implement an option (i.e. `style="latex"`) retrieving the string formatted for LaTeX, which can be inserted through something like `\Sexpr{print_name(Easplist, 206, style="latex")}` (this example is only an hypothetical one).
The output should be then `\textit{Cyperus papyrus} L.` but all my attempts failed because backslash is a scape in R strings.

Is there a way to achieve properly this task?

**Note:** The function is at the moment not implemented in the CRAN version of the package, thus to reproduce the example use the last version from GitHub:

```
devtools::install_github("kamapu/taxlist")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I imagine that you are doing is this:

```
<<example, echo=FALSE>>=
library(taxlist)
data(Easplist)
\Sexpr{print_name(Easplist, 206, style="markdown")}
@
```

Simply move the `\Sexpr{}`to outsite the chunk.

```
<<example, echo=FALSE>>=
library(taxlist)
data(Easplist)
@

\Sexpr{print_name(Easplist, 206, style="markdown")}
```

That will output you what you want.

EDIT:

If you are trying to incorporate "latex" as a style option for the output, then it should look like this when it outputs outside of latex:

```
library(taxlist)
data(Easplist)
print_name(Easplist, 206, style="latex")
[1] "\\textit{Cyperus papyrus} L."
```

The "\" will escape the escape. I did not incorporate it into your function, but here is an example:

```
<<>>=
example_text <- "Cyperus papyrus L."
example_text <- strsplit(example_text, split = " ")
test1 <- paste0("\\textit{", example_text[[1]][1], " ", example_text[[1]][2], "}", 
            " ", example_text[[1]][3])
@

\Sexpr{test1} is a paper reed.
```

The output looks like this in the rendered pdf.

[image]

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, please see my edited answer above.

Comment: Wow! This is really working! Nevertheless it is working only with `knitr` but not with `Sweave`.